# Table not showing on rows correctly when using JSON and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

```
for(var i=0;i<Result.length;i++){
    $('<tr>').appendTo('#resultstable');

    for(var j=0;j<tableID.length;j++){
        $('<td>' + Result[i][tableID[j]] + '</td>').appendTo('#resultstable');
                    }
        $('</tr>').appendTo('#resultstable');
```

When trying to display a table from JSON data, it displays the headers correctly (not shown here), but when I want the data to show on a new row, it doesn't work. The first row of data is shown correctly, but what should be on the second row continues on from the end of the first row.

In the HTML (when loaded), it shows it as:

```
..Table headers..
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
<td>1</td>
...Rest of cell data is put in <td> tags...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add table row in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Comment: The fact that you think you have to append `</tr>` means you don't understand how jQuery appending works. It adds entire DOM elements, it's not concatenating HTML codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because

```
$('<tr>').appendTo('#resultstable');
```

creates `<tr></tr>` dom element and adds it to `#resultstable` table.

With this statement

```
$('<td>' + Result[i][tableID[j]] + '</td>').appendTo('#resultstable');
```

you are not adding html after `<tr>`. You are creating td tag and assigning it to `#resultstable` table. But td tag can be assigned only to `tr` tag.

So the right syntax will be.

```
for(var i=0;i<Result.length;i++){
var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo('#resultstable');

for(var j=0;j<tableID.length;j++) {
    $('<td>' + Result[i][tableID[j]] + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending your data after the table, not after the last row, see [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery/171049#171049) for more information how to add a row after the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You don't append `<td>` elements to the table, you have to append them to the row you just added.

```
for(var i=0;i<Result.length;i++){
    var row = $('<tr>').appendTo('#resultstable');

    for(var j=0;j<tableID.length;j++){
        $('<td>' + Result[i][tableID[j]] + '</td>').appendTo(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be well

```
for(var i=0;i<Result.length;i++){
  var tr =  $('<tr>').appendTo('#resultstable');
  for(var j=0;j<tableID.length;j++){
    $('<td>' + Result[i][tableID[j]] + '</td>').appendTo(tr );
  }
}
```